# XML Parse swift accessing attributeDict

Tags: xml, swift, parsing

How can I get access to AttributeDict in parser function to get columns(name, short and day)? (code is below) I tried something, but it's not working and not finding any help from google either.

Here's the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1257"?>
<timetable ascttversion="2015.5.5" importtype="database" options="daynumbering1,idprefix:Oman" displayname="Oman XML" displaycountries="om" displayinmenu="0">


   <days options="canadd,canremove,canupdate,silent" columns="name,short,day">

      <day name="Esmasp‰ev" short="Es" day="1"/>
      <day name="Teisip‰ev" short="Te" day="2"/>
      <day name="Kolmap‰ev" short="Ko" day="3"/>
      <day name="Neljap‰ev" short="Ne" day="4"/>
      <day name="Reede" short="Re" day="5"/>
   </days>
</timetable>
```

Here is the function:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    elementName
    print("\(elementName)")
//    if attributeDict == ["Name" : "Esmaspäev"] {
//        print("\(attributeDict)")
//    }
    if elementName == "day"
    {
        if elementName == "day"{
            passName=true;
        }
        passData=true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I personally don't like the NSXMLParser APIs, it has bad performance and not easy to use. Try this https://github.com/cezheng/Fuzi

Comment: After creating an XMLDocument instance, you can just use document.root.firstChild(tag: "days") to get the <days> element, then daysElement.children gives you an array of <day> elements, you can access the attributes just using subscript, like dayElement["name"], dayElement["short"], dayElement["day"]

Comment: carthage is only 1 of the 3 ways to import the library. You can also import it with cocoapods or manually

Comment: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage https://guides.cocoapods.org/ FYI

Comment: if you use cocoapods, use the generated xcworkspace rather than the original xcodeproj

Comment: If I open the generated xcworkspace, then it has no AppDelegate.swift, ViewController.swift files, main.storyboard etc. (That may be a ridiculous question) How can I make a project without those initial files?

Comment: your original project is included in the workspace, the pod denpendencies are in a project called 'Pod', just use the included project as before

Comment: The reason you have to use the workspace is that it will compile the dependencies before compiling your project

Comment: What do you mean by "use the included project as before" If I open the generated xcworkspace then it has my project files included, but it has no files or folders in it, only project "pod" has the pod dependencies in it(files and folders).

Comment: thats wierd you can take a screenshot along with your Podfile contents and open another question under cocoapods here since that is a problem with cocoapods usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import Fuzi

func parse() {
    do {
        // Read the xml file as String
        guard 
            let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("arvestusDays", ofType: "xml")
        else {
            print("XML file does not exist.")
            return
        }
        let xmlString = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        // Parse the xml string
        let doc = try XMLDocument(string: xmlString)

        if let days = doc.root.firstChild(tag: "days") {
            for day in days.children {
                print(day["name"])
                print(day["short"])
                print(day["day"])
            }
        }
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

I don't have a Mac with me right now so I can't run to test it, but this code should work. Comment in case it doesn't.

UPDATE:

In case you have encoding problems, try creating the XMLDocument from NSData rather than from String:

```
        let xmlData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)

        // Parse the xml string
        let doc = try XMLDocument(data: xmlData!)
```

Comment: Well, code is not throwing any errors, but in the debug area there are no printed values, it seems like code does nothing? Why it's not showing the printed values in the debugger area?

Comment: I have no clue If it is parsing the values or not, because it's not printing any values to the debug area. Can I somehow check whether the parse is successful or not?

Comment: I have tested the code it is working with your xml file. Note I have just put the code into a function parse() and you have to change that to fit your app's need, ok?

Comment: Thank you So much! I have struggled with the xml parse so long, but finally I am seeing results!